# terminal setup on ubuntu

Tags: ssh

when opening my terminal on ubuntu I get : ilan@ilan-VirtualBox:~$

How do change it ? ( which file should I edit ?) to get only the "$" ?

[image]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

Answer (score -2):

You may use a much more beautiful shell called zsh. I am using the power level 10k theme.

look at my terminal

[image]

It also has better auto-completion, and auto-correction.

Read [this article](https://medium.com/@shivam1/make-your-terminal-beautiful-and-fast-with-zsh-shell-and-powerlevel10k-6484461c6efb) to setup zsh.

you can see the different theme styles

[image]

image taken from github readme of [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k)